# Override DEFINEs in setup.cfg in source eggs

Tags: python, buildout, egg, pysqlite

The source egg of PySQLite 2.6.0 contains a file `setup.cfg` that looks like this:

```
[build_ext]
#define=
#include_dirs=/usr/local/include
#library_dirs=/usr/local/lib
libraries=sqlite3
define=SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION
```

I'd like to build the egg with the `SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION` define **disabled** (not set). I could do that by uncommenting that line in setup.cfg, but I'd like to do this in a `zc.buildout` environment, using `zc.recipe.egg`, `zc.recipe.cmmi`, or any other recipe that could help me.

So, is there an easy way to install PySQLite with extensions enabled but without tampering `setup.cfg`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
[buildout]
parts = pysql

[pysql]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:custom
egg = PySQLite
undef=SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION
```

Comment: zifot, you've just made my day!